# The canonical bundle of an elliptic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Beaville's Complex Algebraic Surface. In Example IX.5, he constructed an elliptic surface of Kodaira dimension $1$: Let B be a smooth curve, $p,q$ the two projections of $B\times\mathbb{P}^2$ onto $B$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$, $|D|$ a base-point free linear system on $B$. A general divisor $S\in |p^*\mathcal{O}_B(D)\otimes q^*\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(3)|$ is smooth; the restriction $p:S\to B$ is a fibration by plane cubics, hence elliptic curves. We have $K_S\equiv p^*(K_B+D)$, and when $\deg D>2-2g(B)$ we have $\kappa(S)=1$.

I have no idea how he computes the canonical divisor of $S$. I just found out that Kodaira's canonical bundle formula is similar but not exactly sure how it is related to this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the canonical bundle $K_S$ of $S$, we use adjunction, which shows that $K_S \equiv (K_{B \times \mathbf{P}^2} + S) \vert_S$. The canonical bundle of $B \times \mathbf{P}^2$ is just $K_{B \times \mathbf{P}^2} \equiv p^{\ast} K_B \otimes q^{\ast} K_{\mathbf{P}^2}$. We know that $K_{\mathbf{P}^2} \equiv \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(-3)$, and hence, $K_{B \times \mathbf{P}^2} \equiv p^{\ast} K_B \otimes q^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(-3)$. Applying the adjunction formula, we see that $$K_S \equiv (p^{\ast} K_B \otimes q^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(-3) + p^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_B(D) \otimes q^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(3) ) \vert_S.$$ From @KReiser's helpful comment (thank you), the $q^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(-3)$ and $q^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^2}(3)$ terms cancel out. Hence, $K_S \equiv p^{\ast} K_B \vert_S + p^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_B(D) \vert_S \equiv p^{\ast}(K_B \otimes \mathcal{O}_B(D) ) \vert_S$, or in the language of divisors, $K_S \equiv p^{\ast}(K_B + D) \vert_S$.

Comment: How should I use adjunction formula? I can show that the restriction of $K_S$ onto a smooth fiber is trivial by adjunction but what's next?

Comment: It's not true that $q^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^2}(3)$ becomes trivial, but that doesn't matter since it cancels with $q^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^2}(-3)$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for pointing out the silly mistake :-)

Comment: This is a nitpick, but I think mixing the additive notation $+$ and the multiplicative notation $\otimes$ in one formula might confuse some readers.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Absolutely, in a formal piece of writing, I would never do that. But this was just a quick answer on MSE :-)